# Read the Docs with nbsphinx

Tags: restructuredtext, read-the-docs, nbsphinx

I created my own `docs` for [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/). See my repository
Some of my docs files are jupyter notebook so I used [nbshpinx](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/) for it.

In my computer I installed all the dependencies and it works great when I use `make html`.
However, Read the docs throws the error:

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.5
loading translations [en]... done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/complex-valued-neural-networks/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 472, in load_extension
    mod = __import__(extname, None, None, ['setup'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbsphinx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/complex-valued-neural-networks/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 303, in build_main
    args.tags, args.verbosity, args.jobs, args.keep_going)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/complex-valued-neural-networks/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.setup_extension(extension)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/complex-valued-neural-networks/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 449, in setup_extension
    self.registry.load_extension(self, extname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/complex-valued-neural-networks/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 475, in load_extension
    raise ExtensionError(__('Could not import extension %s') % extname, err)
sphinx.errors.ExtensionError: Could not import extension nbsphinx (exception: No module named 'nbsphinx')

Extension error:
Could not import extension nbsphinx (exception: No module named 'nbsphinx')
```

Following [this tutorial](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/usage.html#Automatic-Creation-of-HTML-and-PDF-output-on-readthedocs.org) I created two `yml` files and the error changed to:

```
Error
Problem in your project's configuration. Invalid "conda.environment": environment not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!
I followed [this tutorial](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/usage.html#Automatic-Creation-of-HTML-and-PDF-output-on-readthedocs.org)

I added in `readthedocs.yml`:

```
python:
  version: 3
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
  system_packages: true
```

And then in `docs/requirements.txt`:

```
ipykernel
nbsphinx
```

If questions you can always check the [repository](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn/) where I do it.